# Cell Iterator in POI is working in a strange fashion || Frequently skipping the desired rows|| How to solve

Tags: java, excel, iterator, apache-poi

I am trying to parse an excel file using POI, my version in 3.16. My excel is in a tabular format where I have to skip the header where label is Total. My code sometimes skips the column which is Total, sometimes it is not able to skip. I am really clueless about this flow, Here is the screeshot of my excel [image]

So in this excel I have to skip the column Total. And in my code I am picking the label and value both, i.e before Total column there are two columns so I will pick the label as Forecast and the value below the label and so on. But in my case the problem is  after skipping Total the code is getting the value in the next table but can not get the label value, i.e, for Q1  it is only picking the value but can not pick Forecast .

Here is my code ,

```
public class FirstActivity implements Activity {

private static final String SEPARATOR = ";";
private static final int START_ROW = 7;
private int activityId;
private ExcelManager excelManager;

public FirstActivity(int activityId, ExcelManager excelManager) {
    this.activityId = activityId;
    this.excelManager = excelManager;
}

@Override
public List<String> start() {
    ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Activity number " + activityId + " started");
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    Workbook workbook = excelManager.getWorkbook();
    for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
        result.addAll(processSheet(workbook.getSheetAt(i)));
    }
    ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Activity number " + activityId + " completed");
    return result;
}

@Override
public List<String> processSheet(Sheet sheet) {
    ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Processing sheet " + sheet.getSheetName() + " started");
    List<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();
    String sheetName = sheet.getSheetName().toUpperCase();
    /* skip the sheets name containing TOTAL or LOB */
    if (sheetName.contains("TOTAL") || sheetName.contains("LOB")) {
        ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Sheet " + sheet.getSheetName() + " skipped");
        return rows;
    }


    String aCellValue = "";
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    int rowCount = 0;

    rowsloop: while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        rowCount++;

        Iterator<Row> rowIteratorTotal = sheet.iterator();
        int rowCountTotal = 0;
        Row currentRowTotal = null;
        Iterator<Cell> cellIteratorTotal = null;
         while (rowIteratorTotal.hasNext()) {
            rowCountTotal++;
            currentRowTotal = rowIteratorTotal.next();
            /* start processing from the specified row */
            if (rowCountTotal < 9) {
                continue;
            }
            else 
                cellIteratorTotal = currentRowTotal.iterator();
                break;
         }


        Row currentRow = rowIterator.next();
        /* start processing from the specified row */
        if (rowCount < START_ROW) {
            continue;
        }
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();
        StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
        row.append(sheetName);
        row.append(SEPARATOR);

        int cellCount = 0;
        String lastACellValue = "";



        while (cellIterator.hasNext() && cellIteratorTotal.hasNext()) {

            cellCount++;
            Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();

            Cell currentCellTotal = cellIteratorTotal.next();


            String cellValue = excelManager.evalCell(currentCell);

            String cellValueTotal = excelManager.evalCell(currentCellTotal);


            /* A Cell process */
            if (cellCount == 1) {
                lastACellValue = cellValue;
                /*
                 * in case the A cell contains the word total then break the
                 * cycle and process the next row
                 */
                if ((cellValue.toLowerCase().contains("total") && (!cellValue.toLowerCase().contains("total interest result intercompany")))) {

                    row = new StringBuilder();
                    break ;
                } /*
                     * the sheet processing ends when the row starts with FA
                     * INVESTMENT
                     */
                /*else if (cellValue.toUpperCase().contains("FA INVESTMENT")) {
                    ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("cell " + cellValue.toString() + " found. Sheet processing will exit");
                    break rowsloop;
                }*/
                // if 
                cellValue = (aCellValue.isEmpty()) ? cellValue : aCellValue;
            } /* B Cell process */

            else if (cellCount == 2) {
                if ((cellValue.toLowerCase().contains("total") && (!cellValue.toLowerCase().contains("total interest result intercompany"))) || /* row empty check */ cellValue.isEmpty()) {
                    row = new StringBuilder();
                    break;
                } else if (!lastACellValue.isEmpty()) {
                    /*
                     * update the aCellValue when both A and B cell are not
                     * empty
                     */
                    aCellValue = lastACellValue;
                    /*
                     * rebuild the row with the sheet name and the updated
                     * aCellValue
                     */
                    row = new StringBuilder();
                    row.append(sheetName + SEPARATOR + aCellValue + SEPARATOR);

                }
            }


                if ((cellCount <= 2 && !cellValue.isEmpty() && (!cellValueTotal.toLowerCase().contains("total")) ) ||
                (cellCount > 2 && !cellValue.isEmpty() && (!cellValueTotal.toLowerCase().contains("total")) )){
                ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Processing sheet " + sheet.getSheetName() + " " + cellValue + cellValueTotal);
                row.append(cellValue) ;
                row.append(SEPARATOR);
            }
        }

        if (!row.toString().isEmpty()) {
            rows.add(row.toString());
        }
    }
    ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Processing sheet " + sheet.getSheetName() + " completed");
    return rows;
}

@Override
public int getActivityId() {
    return this.activityId;
}

@Override
public void setActivityId(int activityId) {
    this.activityId = activityId;
}

}
```

This is the complete code, the problem may sound sily but I really can not find any clue. Please help.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea about this ?

Comment: @Gagravarr  can you help me in this ?

Comment: @ Sirmyself can you look at this ?